# How do you create virtual folders from saved search

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, bsd, fuse

I would like to have on unix-like platforms, the same functionality as to [Windows 7 Library folders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Explorer#Libraries) (aka [virtual folders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_folder)) you see in Windows Explorer.

Gnome Nautilus do that kind of virtual folders through [saved search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_folder#GNOME). But I want a system-wide solution, not a gnome-wide solution.

Is there a tool that creates virtual folders from the concatenation of multiple search queries (the result of multiple `find` commands ?). The solution should index files for better performances and you should be able to define the default folder for copy operations.

I assume the solution of this kind of problem certainly use [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/), but I can't see a complete solution to this kind of task in [FUSE applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace#Examples).

**Is there any existing solution to this problem (involving no development from my side) ?**

Comment: I think that at this point in time this is a *programming* question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's an application feature, not a system one.  (just curious, do those windows 7 folders appear on a shell `dir` command?).

Both Gnome and KDE have a filesystem-like API, [GVFS](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gnome-vfs-2.0/) on Gnome and [kio](http://api.kde.org/4.x-api/kdelibs-apidocs/kio/html/index.html) on KDE.  There are FUSE systems based on [each](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=FileSystems#GnomeVFS2_FUSE) [one](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=FileSystems#KIO_Fuse_Gateway), so if the functionality you see on your filebrowser is based on either, there's hope.

Comment: @Javier, the Libraries are an Explorer feature, they don't exist at all on disk (except the XML configuration file). The only reason the Libraries appear in the Open/Save dialogs is that many applications make use of new APIs that support them.

Comment: @Chris S: thanks, so windows is on the same footing as KDE, at least; where most applications accept the same kio refrences as Konqueror.